# nth-child of every other div's children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make the background color of the div's INSIDE reportRow to have a specific background color but I want it to switch colors every other reportRow.

I can't seem to get nth-child to work. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="reportRow">
    <div style="width:75px;">Date1</div>
    <div style="width:360px;">Address1</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Edit1</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Print1</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Delete1</div>
</div>

<div class="reportRow">
    <div style="width:75px;">Date2</div>
    <div style="width:360px;">Address2</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Edit2</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Print2</div>
    <div style="width:40px;">Delete2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/t75Zu/
You want to use nth-child on reportRow, but set the inner div's background

```
.reportRow:nth-child(2n) div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to target every other nth-child, here's an example of what you should have in your CSS:

```
.reportRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

You can replace the parameter with even or odd as well as a couple of other things. Here's some documentation on the nth-child psuedo-class: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp.